# Pyqt4 X errors when starting aplication

Tags: python, pyqt4, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm making a program for my raspberry pi in python and pyqt4.
Now I'm starting the program on my raspberry and it gives errors and it doesn't show the buttons I have made.
I have designed into qtdesinger, it shows the window but nothing on it.

This is the error i have:

```
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied) 10
  Extension:    129 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 1 (X_ShmAttach)
  Resource id:  0x2800001
X Error: BadShmSeg (invalid shared segment parameter) 128
  Extension:    129 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 5 (X_ShmCreatePixmap)
  Resource id:  0x280000a
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x280000b
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x280000b
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x280000b
```

This my python code from the qtdesigner:

```
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(480, 640)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 140, 83, 24))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.toolButton = QtGui.QToolButton(Form)
        self.toolButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 250, 27, 20))
        self.toolButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("toolButton"))
        self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(Form)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 280, 156, 24))
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDia$
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buttonBox"))
        self.commandLinkButton = QtGui.QCommandLinkButton(Form)
        self.commandLinkButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 230, 168, 41))
        self.commandLinkButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("commandLinkButton"))
        self.checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(Form)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 380, 84, 19))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox"))
        self.toolButton_2 = QtGui.QToolButton(Form)
        self.toolButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 470, 27, 20))
        self.toolButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("toolButton_2"))
        self.listView = QtGui.QListView(Form)
        self.listView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 460, 256, 192))
        self.listView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listView"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, QtG$
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Lamp", None,$
        self.toolButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "...", None, $
        self.commandLinkButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Comma$
        self.checkBox.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "CheckBox", Non$
        self.toolButton_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "...", None$
```

and this my file to show the window:
    import sys
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
    from test import Ui_Widget

```
class StartQT4(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Widget()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = StartQT4()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Does have annybody a solution for me?
I googled the error but found no answers for my problem.

Thanks...

Comment: It's it possible that the problem real VNC is? I want to start the program into a vnc session. On the internet they say that the problem maybe real vnc is? Could it be possible?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with a python app.

I have found the following:

1. Using VNC, login to Gnome desktop as myself and run application as myself, works 100%
2. While logged into desktop as myself, run xhost +
3. Sudo switch user to another user and the application fails
4. As the new user, export DISPLAY=hostname:
5. Run the app and now it works 100%

This started happening with a python update which included newer versions of pyqt and libqt.

As a side test, I am eable to run "eyes" and "firefox" perfectly (without exporting display variable)

The problem appears to sit when pyqt atempts to "fill in" an X11 window when using "/unix" MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 .....the same routines work when using "hostname:instance"  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1

Answer (score 1):

I found similar problem with Unetbootin. It requires root privileges, and when X-server is started from user, e.g. using `startx` command, it gives the same error.

Solution is to use display manager, like lxdm, gdm and such.

My guess is that QT can't elevate permission to access some shared memory, because X is running with *user* privileges. And with desktop manager it runs with root privileges.